# Trying to create a stored procedure in mysql (phpmyadmin) but it won't work. i can't se what's wrong

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Testproc1`;

CREATE PROCEDURE Testproc1
(

```
IN p_klassekode CHAR(3),
IN p_klassenavn VARCHAR(30)
```

)

BEGIN

```
INSERT INTO klasse VALUES(p_klassekode, p_klassenavn);
```

END

CALL Testproc1 ('TS1','testklasse');

Comment: GO? That's sql server.

Comment: "It won't work" is never a good error description.

Comment: How many columns in klasse?

Comment: oh.. i have removed that, but it still wrong. this is the error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE PROCEDURE Testproc1
(
    IN p_klassekode CHAR(3),
    IN p_klassenavn' at line 3

Comment: it's two columns in klasse

Comment: Every statement has to be terminated with ; your drop procedure does not.

Comment: I tried that, and now i got this error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 7